# How to know when I come back to activity from dialog in Jetpack Comopse

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple compose dialog, I need to know when I dismiss the dialog away and comeback to the activity so that I can trigger a function in that activity. This function should ONLY trigger after I dismiss the dialog. How/If I should pass a parameter into this dialog? How do make it so know when Im coming back to the activity? Here's the actvity:

```
binding.impersonateSection.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
            var openDialog= remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                ButtonComponent(
                    onClick = {openDialog.value = true}
                               )

                                if (openDialog.value) {
                                   MyCustomDialogPopUp(openDialog)
                                 }
```

and then my composable dialog looks like:

```
fun CustomDialogPopUp(openDialogBox: MutableState<Boolean>) {
    AlertDialog(
        title = { Text("Are you sure you want to delete this?") },
            dismissButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = { openDialogBox= false }) {
                Text("Cancel".uppercase())
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass the Activity function to the Dialog and call it when the Dialog is dismissed. See the following example how to pass an Activity function references to a Composable:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //...

        binding.impersonateSection.apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                var openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                ButtonComponent(
                    onClick = {openDialog.value = true}
                )

                if (openDialog.value) {
                    // We pass an Activity Function Reference to the Dialog
                    MyCustomDialogPopUp(openDialog, ::activityFunction)
                }
           }
    }

    fun activityFunction(param: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(this, param.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And then in your Dialog Composable:

```
fun CustomDialogPopUp(
    openDialogBox: MutableState<Boolean>, 
    onDismissCallback: (returnValue: Int) -> Unit
) {
    AlertDialog(
        title = { Text("Are you sure you want to delete this?") },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(onClick = { openDialogBox = false; onDismissCallback(123) }) {
                Text("Cancel".uppercase())
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a `Boolean` value that dictates whether the dialog is open or not, have a sealed class or an enum that does that.
You could have 3 states: `Visible`, `Invisible` and `Idle` where the latter is the initial state. This way every time you are on `Invisible`, it means that the user must have opened and then closed the dialog so you are back to the parent view and you can reset to Idle, otherwise if you are on the parent view for the first time it would be `Idle` and if the dialog is open it must be `Visible`.

```
sealed class DialogState {
    object Visible : DialogState()
    object Invisible : DialogState()
    object Idle : DialogState()

}
...
setContent {
    var openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(DialogState.Idle) }
    ButtonComponent(
        onClick = {openDialog.value = Visible}
    )

    when (openDialog.value) {
        is Idle -> Unit // or do whathever
        is Visible -> MyCustomDialogPopUp(openDialog)
        is Invisible -> // do what you must do when you are back and then reset to Idle
    }
}
```